Python Issue making folder outside of current directory
So I'm able to create folders in the same path as my main.py is in. But even with using os.chdir and try to create an folder into that directory I'm unable to. It can read if an folder like that exist but the part to mkdir just doesn't do anything. I don't get a print, etc. I did notice the folder is in "read only" but the folder the main.py is in a subfolder of that folder and can create one just fine. When I check that directory it says theres writeable access.
import os
    default_path = os.getcwd()
    new_path = ""
    print("Current directory:", default_path)
    if(input("Do you want to change the directory? (y/n): ") == "y"):
        new_path = input("You can use relative path or absolute path \nEnter the new directory: ")
        new_path = os.path.abspath(new_path)
        if os.path.exists(new_path):
            os.chdir(new_path)
            print("Directory changed to", os.getcwd())
            print(os.access(os.getcwd(), os.W_OK))
        else:
            print("Directory does not exist.")
    
    day_to_start = input("Number to start with(Ex: type 1 for Day 1): ").strip()
    day_to_end = input("Amount to create: ").strip()
    for i in range(int(day_to_start), int(day_to_end) + 1):
        if os.path.exists(f"Day {i}"):
            print(f"Day {i} already exists.")
        else:
            os.mkdir(f"Day {i}")
            print(f"Day {i} created.")


What's the error message?

Also, make sure your indentation is correct. Why are everything after import get indented?

@pepoluan sorry its not indented in my code when I copy pasted it here it must of got indented somehow. I'm not getting any error code when I run it, it just doesn't do the else part in the for loop if I'm not in the same directory as my main.py is. If I run it in the same directory as main.py it works perfectly fine. But I'm trying to create folders outside of that folder and I get nothing.

Sorry I found my issue after a long time of debugging lol.
for i in range(int(day_to_start), int(day_to_end) + 1):

was incorrect so the loop wouldn't run once day_to_start was higher than day_to_end which is why it wasn't creating the folders..
I've adjusted it to
for i in range(day_to_start, day_to_start + day_to_end):

